# Assigning Variable to address a Row in VBA (Office 2019)

Tags: vba, variables, row

Created a Variable x and assigned it an integer value, then used it to address a row.R[x] C[2] But gives error.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To get accurate answers, you should write what is your target and what problem is making you stuck (including error messages), attach the portion of code interested and also explain what you've tried to solve the issues

Comment: You need to look up how to reference ranges in vba. For example here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/reference-cells-and-ranges. One way is to use  `Cells(x, 2)`

Answer (score 0):

1. In VBA you do not obtain a better memory load using `Integer`. So, cultivate the habit to always use `Dim x As Long`, please.
2. `row.R[x] C[2]` does not have a meaning in VBA. Try the next approach, please:

```
Dim X as Long
X = 2
MsgBox Cells(X, X).Address 'it will return the address of Row 2, Columns 2 ($B$2)
'Or
MsgBox Range("A" & X).Address 'returns "$A$2"
```